# How can i get pass get the element using id, not name to $_POST['']

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the data by $_POST[''] but i need to get it by id.
How can i do that?

I tried `$_POST['#id']`

I want PHP to receive the data from the element:

```
<div id="phone">+256785589992</div>
```

Comment: Wanna post the data via javascript / ajax?  Why do you even have this problem / restriction? How are posting this data anyhow? I don't see a form or input fields.

Comment: Use javascript to rewrite ids to names. Forms only work off of names. Of course, this won't work anyway as a form, since it's a div and not an input.

Comment: can't use inputs with name attributes?

Comment: What you're asking for is too broad and unclear. It would be **beneficial for you** to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Please read through that and you'll see how Stack Overflow works, *"learning the ropes"* as it were. It will give you a good idea on how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help you have a better and positive experience here, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `javascript` and a hidden input with `php` and submit the form using the input name

```
 <script>
        document.querySelector("input-hidden").value = document.querySelector("phone").innerHTML;
    </script>
```

Comment: How will i add the name?

Comment: you will take the name of your hidden input to submit the form, and the script will replace the input value with the phone number from  your html element

Comment: Thanks very much but where should i put the code above? in the html or php file

Comment: you can put it in the php file

Comment: assume this the portin of the code in php, if '(isset($_POST['register'])) {
  $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'sarahma8_farmers', 'farmers123', 'sarahma8_agadvisor');

  $name = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
  $mobile = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['mobile']);
  $email = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $password = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['password_1']);
  $cPassword = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['password_2']);
  $phone = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['PhoneNumber']);
  
   if (empty($phone)) {
  array_push($errors, "-phone is required.");
 }'